# Определить, пропустить в условии каждую секунду

Tags: javascript

Проигрывается аудио, висит слушатель ontimeupdate. В итоге он срабатывает, вывожу время, на выходе получаю

```
0.047634
0.435724
0.604783
0.868743
1.121717
1.884108
1.953165
```

Необходимо привязать ко времени проигрывания, а так как слушатель срабатывает в тысячных. Необходимо условие в этом самом слушателе, которое будет пропускать в том случаи если прошла 1 целая секунда.

В данный момент делаю так. Округляю значение, запоминаю его в переменной и при следующем срабатывание. Беру текущее целое число и сравниваю его с предыдущим, если не совпадают, значит прошла 1 секунда.

Как то это не правильно, возможно делать подобные операции проще?

Comment: Ну вообще не правильно то, что вы делаете, даже если сдвиг был в десятых или сотых, это всё равно сдвиг.

Comment: Как мне быть. Необходимо посекундно считать, то есть выполнять код каждую секунду, главное чтобы была привязка ко времени проигрыванию аудио.

Comment: Погодите, а у вас аудио что-ли отдельно? Что вы вообще хотите сделать с этим, можете, пожалуйста, объяснить? Возможно вы не добавили достаточно подробностей в вопрос.

Comment: Необходимо включить рекламу. К примеру пользователь слушает дорожку или смотрит видео. Необходимо сделать посекундный отсчет, но отсчет необходимо выполнить, привязав его к проигрыванию. Так к примеру необходимо сделать возможным, в том случаи когда есть кнопка пропустить, но пропустить необходимо по истечению 10 секунд проигрывания.

Comment: Таймауты или интервалы не подойдут, поскольку проигрывание может подвисать....

Comment: Ну тут не всё так просто, пользователь может просто промотать видео и тогда "пройдёт" больше времени чем ожидалось, нужно создать отдельную переменную и уже к ней прибавлять +1, когда проходит секунда, если в видео (рекламе) можно нельзя промотать, тогда всё легко, если же нет, тогда всё сложнее чем кажется...

Comment: Когда реклама запущена, промотать нельзя. Я так и делаю к примеру `(t = Math.floor(this.v.currentTime)) != this.rk && (this.rk = t)` Быть может иначе возможно выполнить, чтобы лишний раз не объявлять переменную?

Comment: На моей памяти, способов без объявления "лишней" переменной, нет.